# nodejs raspberry pi led not blinking

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to blink a LED raspberry pi and nodejs. I am using the onoff module. All my connections are fine as I have tested the same using python. Using python the LED is blinking just fine. But the nodejs program runs but LED does not blink. The code is attached below.

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var LED = new Gpio(4, 'out');
var blinkInterval = setInterval(blinkLED, 500);

function blinkLED() {
    if(LED.readSync === 0) {
        LED.writeSync(1);
    } else {
        LED.writeSync(0);
    }
}

function endBlink() {
    clearInterval(blinkInterval);
    LED.writeSync(0);
    LED.unexport();
}

setTimeout(endBlink, 5000);
```